# GoogleSheet Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to compare the values between two cells in different columns to locate errors quickly. I want the color in one cell to change if the value is not the same as the adjacent cell.

Answer (score 0):

use a custom formula in conditional formatting like `=A1=B1` let's say on range **A1:B**

or some more complexity:

```
=($B1=$C1)*($C1<>"")*($B1<>"")
```

[image: 0]